# Data not updating on view side Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have a list of menu counts for displaying total data available for that page. And I try to update menu count data after creating new records by calling a method. Here the problem is my data is updated but the view is not updating.
MenuCount is an array which contains the following types of data

```
"[{"MenuId":"ContactCount","CountTotal":26},{"MenuId":"ContactActiveCount","CountTotal":25},{"MenuId":"ContactInActiveCount","CountTotal":1},{"MenuId":"ContactReviewerCount","CountTotal":10},{"MenuId":"ContactApplicantCount","CountTotal":0},{"MenuId":"ContactManagerCount","CountTotal":0},{"MenuId":"ReviewerActiveCount","CountTotal":10},{"MenuId":"ReviewerInActiveCount","CountTotal":0},{"MenuId":"ReviewPanelCount","CountTotal":13},{"MenuId":"ReviewPanelActiveCount","CountTotal":13},{"MenuId":"ReviewPanelInActiveCount","CountTotal":0},{"MenuId":"ReviewerSolicitationCount","CountTotal":1},{"MenuId":"ReviewerSolicitationActiveCount","CountTotal":1},{"MenuId":"ReviewerSolicitationInctiveCount","CountTotal":0},{"MenuId":"OrganizationCount","CountTotal":37},{"MenuId":"OrganizationActiveCount","CountTotal":37},{"MenuId":"OrganizationInActiveCount","CountTotal":0},{"MenuId":"DocumentActiveCount","CountTotal":0},{"MenuId":"ProgramCount","CountTotal":213},{"MenuId":"ProgramActiveCount","CountTotal":213},{"MenuId":"ProgramInActiveCount","CountTotal":0},{"MenuId":"FundingOpptyCount","CountTotal":71},{"MenuId":"PendingAnnouncementCount","CountTotal":1},{"MenuId":"DraftAnnouncementCount","CountTotal":67},{"MenuId":"ArchivedAnnouncementCount","CountTotal":0},{"MenuId":"ClosedAnnouncementCount","CountTotal":2},{"MenuId":"OpenAnnouncementCount","CountTotal":2},{"MenuId":"OpenReviewCount","CountTotal":0},{"MenuId":"OpenAwardCount","CountTotal":1},{"MenuId":"ApplicantTotalCount","CountTotal":60},{"MenuId":"ApplicantUnassignedCount","CountTotal":16},{"MenuId":"ApplicantInReviewCount","CountTotal":6},{"MenuId":"ApplicantInReviewCompletedCount","CountTotal":32},{"MenuId":"ApplicantAwardedCount","CountTotal":4},{"MenuId":"ApplicantDeclinedCount","CountTotal":2},{"MenuId":"MyApplicationCount","CountTotal":0},{"MenuId":"MyApplicantCount","CountTotal":0}]"
```

Refer image below:

[image]

I am showing that count by call getMenuCount() function in the component

```js
MenuCount: any[] = [];

LoadMenuCountList(): void {

  this._apiService.get("Common/GetMenuCount")
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.MenuCount = [];
        this.MenuCount = data.ListCount;
        console.log(this.MenuCount);
        this.isUserLoggedin = true;
      },
      error => {
        this.isUserLoggedin = false;
      });
}
getMenuCount(lname) {
  if (this.MenuCount != null)
    var objSng = this.MenuCount.find((obj) => obj.MenuId == lname);
  if (objSng != null)
    return objSng.CountTotal;

}
```

```html
<span class="m-menu__link-text">
PROGRAMS
<span class="left-menu-number">              
    {{getMenuCount('ProgramCount')}}
</span>
</span>
```

After adding new Programs I update that MenuCount list then the data is updated  like ProgramCount became 214 and I console it but on the view side, it's showing old ProgramCount 213

```
{"MenuId":"ProgramCount","CountTotal":214}
```

Comment: Are you using OnPush as change detection strategy?

Comment: The problem is that yes, you are updating the menuCount, but that doesnt meant that the function `getMenuCount(args)` will be automatically called. I would run the function everytime `this.MenuCount` changes, you  and assign the result to a variable, and use that variable in the template.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz no